# Populate Arrays using Lodash

Tags: javascript, arrays, lodash

Using [lodash](https://lodash.com), how can I "*populate*" an array of keys using values from another array as following:

```
let array = [{ obj: myObject, val: 42, ref: 4 }, { val: 100, ref: 1 }];
let refs = [{ key: 4, msg: 'Hello' }, { key: 1, msg: 'there' }]
// populate array[i].ref with refs[i].key
response = populate(array, refs, {key: 'ref', foreingKey: 'key'})

/* 
 response = [
     { obj: myObject, val: 42, ref: { key: 4, msg: 'Hello'} }, 
     { val: 100, ref: {key: 1, msg: 'There'} }
   ];
 */
```

Actually, I'm iterating both arrays manually, but I cannot figured out how can it be done with Lodash.

Comment: Does ref = key, or are you just adding the objects from the corresponding index in the other array? If the former, your expected output is wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming the keys and refs are unique:

```
const lookup = _.keyBy(refs, 'key');
const response = _.map(array, x => _.merge(x, {ref: lookup[x.ref]}));
```

Short explanation: the first line creates a lookup hash for efficiency reasons. The second line merges every object in your array with an item in the lookup hash that matches the value of ref with key.

Answer (score 0):

```
const temp = []; 
let array = [
  { obj: myObject, val: 42, ref: 4 }, 
  { val: 100, ref: 1 }
]; 
let refs = [
  { key: 4, msg: 'Hello' }, 
  { key: 1, msg: 'there' }
]; 

array.forEach(x =>{ 
  refs.forEach(y => { 
    if (x.refs === y.key) { 
      temp.push({ ...x, ...y }) 
    } 
  }) 
})
```